# How can I get values from a list (not having items ids) with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-lists

So I have a list with lots of items like below:

```
<ul id="usersList">
   <li><FORM><INPUT class="eButton" type="button" value="robot669394444" onClick="openWin('robot669394444',1280,720)"></FORM></li> 
   <li><FORM><INPUT class="eButton" type="button" value="robot6693925" onClick="openWin('robot6693925',1280,720)"></FORM></li> 
</ul>
```

I want to get all INPUT values using jQuery into an array. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var vals = $("form input").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
});
```

Alternatively (more cleanly)

```
var vals = [];
$("form input").each(function() {
  vals.push( $(this).val() );
});
```

The second alternative is more clean since it leaves you with a plain vanilla array. The result of `map()` *still* is a jQuery object. Since these are (and behave exactly like) arrays, this might not be a problem. But it's useful to keep that subtle difference in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of a way to do it with Jquery, but using simple javascript can help

```
var uL=document.getElementById("usersList");
var i=0;
var inArr=new Array();
while(uL.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[i]){

  inArr.push(uL.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
  alert(inArr[i].value);
  i++;

}
```

`inArr` will contain all the input element objects in it...

Answer (score 1):

It's not always possible to store all params (keys and values) in an object, because two inputs can have same name.

But you can use: `$('form.myform').serializeArray()` to get an object like `[{param1:value2}, {param2: value2}]`

Or use 
`$('form.myform').serializeArray().map(function(e){ return e.value;})`
to get list of all values `[value1, value2, ...]`